# Groovy Beta install error on OSX

Tags: ros, groovy-beta, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the [instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) in section 2.2.2, the ROS-Comm install doesn't work. Going to `http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/dry/raw/groovy/ros_comm` returns the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/dry/raw/groovy/ros_comm

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'dajaxice',
 'dajax',
 'prerelease_website.submit_jobs',
 'prerelease_website.rosinstall_gen')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/prerelease_website/prerelease_website/rosinstall_gen/views.py" in dry_raw
  11.     rosinstall = generate_dry_rosinstall(distro, variant)
File "/var/www/prerelease_website/prerelease_website/rosinstall_gen/old_distro.py" in generate_dry_rosinstall
  14.                                                 variant_name=variant)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/rospkg/distro.py" in distro_to_rosinstall
  287.         stack_names = set(variant.get_stack_names(implicit=implicit))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /rosinstall/generate/dry/raw/groovy/ros_comm
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_stack_names'
```

Both the full-desktop and desktop seem to work fine (they return a list of packages to install).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51171/groovy-beta-install-error-on-osx/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're trying to generate a rosinstall file for a wet stack with the dry toolchain. Can you try this instead?

http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/ros_comm

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2012-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-12-29**:
Yes that returns a list of packages. @WilliamWoodall is leveraging the "install from source" instructions for linux. They want us to build a dry tool chain first it appears. I am just trying to let them know it is broken for ros_comm, but works for the other two.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-12-29**:
Yes, this should not be used in the case of ros_comm.  We are intending to replace ros_comm with an actual variant in the future. But the rosinstall generate could give a more meaningful response, like `# No dry packages selected` or something similar, which would result in an empty rosinstall.

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2012-12-29**:
I updated the installation instructions to reflect this.